# Add CSS Class to reStructuredText internal reference

Tags: css, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to format an internal link - defined with `:ref:` - in my documentation using CSS classes.

My problem is that I cannot convert `` :ref:`Link <internal_link> `` to the following bit of HTML `<a href="internal_link" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Link</a>`

I've tried defining a new `role` but that was unsuccessful too.

```
.. role:: ref
   :class: btn btn-sm btn-primary

:ref:`Link <internal_link>`
```

My current solution is to use raw html and render it as such, but I cannot link the RST files but have to point to the HTML files instead (which doesn't work for PDF output).

```
.. role:: raw-html(raw)
   :format: html

:raw-html:`<a href="internal_link.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Link</a>`
```

Does anyone know how to add custom CSS classes to `:ref:`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about getting the class in the link directly. But you should be able to get it in the parent with:

```
.. cssclass:: btn-primary

  :ref:`link`
```

then adjust the css selector to use:

```
.btn-primary a
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. One question, how do I make the entire button the link and not just the text within?

Comment: good question.  not sure if you really can, or if there's a CSS trick.

Comment: I thought so, maybe somebody figures this out in the future. Thanks anyway!